# Datepicker not getting cleaned using angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datepicker

I have HTML after submitting the form the resetting all the input fields to blank. But, the datepicker alone not getting cleaned.

**HTML code**

```
  <div>
                      <form name="profileform" role="form"> 
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <h4 class="mzero">Details</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">                             
                          <input type="text" placeholder="name"  name="name" ng-model="personal.name">                            
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group input-daterange input-group col-xs-12" id="datepicker">                                  
                          <input value="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="dob" name="dob" ng-model="personal.dob">                             
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                          <textarea  rows="2" placeholder="Write about you..." name="description" ng-model="personal.description" ></textarea>
                          </div>
                      </form>
              </div>
```

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="createChallenge()">Create</button> 

   </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({  
         startDate: "today" 
    }); 
  });
```

**JS Code**

```
$scope.createChallenge = function(){
// persist in db logic 
 resetForm();     
}

 var resetForm = function(){
           $scope.master={};
               $scope.profile= angular.copy($scope.master);     
            $scope.profileform.$setPristine();

                  };
```

All the input fields are resetted but in datepicker window the previously selected date still exists. I want to clear that.

Comment: put datepicker code in a directive so you can watch the model and trigger a change on the input after reset, or use datepicker API to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter said you should create a directive for the datepicker.

```
    var datePicker = function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function(scope, element) {

                element.datepicker({
                    startDate: "today"
                });

            }
        }
    };

angular.module('your_module_name')
    .directive('datePicker', datePicker);
```

and then use this directive in your html

```
<div class="form-group input-daterange input-group col-xs-12">                                  
  <input date-picker value="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="dob" name="dob" ng-model="personal.dob">                             
</div>
```

#### Edit

Created working example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JejtFpUgPpH5okBBElIC?p=preview).

Comment: I just need to know whether to give the directive name in the HTML as date-picker or datepicker

Comment: Angular converts - or _ delimited directive names to camel case. So if the directive is `datePicker` (capital P) in javascript it is `date-picker` in html and if it's `datepicker` (small p) in js then it will be `datepicker` in html.

Comment: I tried your code but my directive is not at all invoked I tried with alert message also but the message is not printing since the directive is not invoked

Comment: I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JejtFpUgPpH5okBBElIC?p=preview) which has this directive working in.